# Favicon .ico vs hospedagem

Tags: html, imagem, hospedagem, icons

Existe alguma forma ( Site ) de eu hospedar um arquivo `.ico` sem que seja no ' servidor ' da aplicação, digo fazer como normalmente fazemos o upload de uma imagem `.jpg` / `.png` em sites como [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) ?

Em grande parte da minha pesquisa antes de fazer está pergunta, o google confundia o `ico` com outros termos e por conseguinte os resultados não eram o que eu esperava, porém oque encontrei até agora foi :

[Is there a free service where i can host a favicon ( .ico ) file ?](https://www.reddit.com/r/webhosting/comments/2iktqo/is_there_a_free_service_where_i_can_host_a/) ( Todas opções citadas estão quebradas )

[Using .ico in img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932591/using-ico-in-img-tag) ( Sem relação )

[Favicon: como criar e hospedar imagens .ico](http://www.dicasblogger.com.br/2009/02/favicon-criar-hospedar-imagens-ico.html) ( Novamente sem relação )

Dentre outros meios ( Como a comunidade front-end ) que também não souberam me informar uma ( Boa ) opção ...

Comment: Pergunta: por quê não hospedar o arquivo no próprio servidor?

Comment: Como no primeiro link que encontrei em minha pesquisa, é para um blog no tumblr.

Comment: o iconj.com pareceu funcionar em um teste preliminar que fiz

Comment: talvez relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497010/how-do-i-delete-tumblrs-default-favicon

Comment: Vlw, e o site que enviou no primeiro comentário não funciona, ele só converte a imagem para `.ico` e na segunda aba que deveria hospedar ele manda um link que redireciona pro favicon deles mesmos. ( O link to Stf ajudou ! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro vou lhe indicar um serviço, todavia o motivo da resposta é explicar algo sobre os *favicons* que poderá lhe ser útil.

### "Hospedagem" (Host) favicons

Pesquisando encontrei esta http://www.iconj.com/icon_generator.php, além de "hospedar" ele também converte sua imagem para ícone.

### Ícones e Imagens como favicon

Navegadores antigos costumavam usar apenas `.ico`, isto quando suportado, pois existiam navegadores que nem suportavam, então a preferencia sempre foi usar este formato, no entanto a maioria dos navegadores modernos como pode ver na lista suportam png: http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-png

[image: png icon]

**Ou seja**, o `.ico` não é mais a única opção, você pode hospedar em diferentes sites ou usar diferentes domínios para armazenar imagens `.png` e apontar elas no seu site:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://3rd.site.com/img/favicon.png">
```

### iOS Safari e os favicons

Você deve ter notado que os favicons não estão disponíveis no Safari para iOS, nem mesmo o formato `.ico`, no entanto o Safari tem uma tag `link` própria para ícones quando você salva nos favoritos ou para o "Home" e é compatível com muitas versões do Android, são as tags:

- `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icone-grande.png">` quando adicionar aos favoritos ou adicionar ao `Home` (junto aos aplicativos)
- `<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="icone-grande.png">` o `-precomposed` faz com que o ícone não recebe o efeito de *"gloss"* no ícone.

As imagens [*devem ser PNG conforme a documentação*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), esses ícones ficam semelhante a isto (exemplo usando o site do Youtube) na Home (esquerda) e na hora de adicionar aos favoritos ou a "lista de leitura" (direita):

[image: apple-touch-icon na Home e nos Favoritos]

> **Nota:** na verdade eu acho que reconhece sim `<link rel="icon">`, apesar do **caniuse** dizer que não, mas a imagem fica "feia", no entanto funciona (ao menos aonde testei) se não tiver o `apple-touch-icon` definido.

Comment: Muito bom, eu já tinha visto isso em Android e iOS, mas não tinha procurado as tags ( Pois esqueci ), vlw.